# Using Data Structure Objects to store data in Android

Tags: android

I am a newbie to android. My question is not about how to do something, but more on the idea I have in mind is optimized or not.

I am creating a Chat App. The biggest issue I was facing was storing Non persistent data, coz whenever the activity closed, all data was lost. The biggest problem was when user moved from Chat Screen (Chat Activity) to Peoples List (Peoples Activity) all data was lost again, and if user reinitited chat, he couldnt see the history.

As a workaround, I am creating a few data classes, and a service. The service stores data in the classes, whenever it receives an update from activity or the server. After that on each new activity I will just pass around this object from one activity to another and service.

I would like some recommendations in this, Is this a good way to go around? Thanks for your precious time.

Answer (score 3):

If I've understood properly, you need a way to store data of variables or the content of one data structure or whatever and don't lose this data when your app change across severals  activities, right? You need save state across several Activities.

First solution: in Java, one solution for this problem could be to use "static" variables. You can do it but using Android, we can use a more elegant solution.

Second and recommended solution:  Associate the state with the Application Context (easy)

You should create your own subclass of android.app.Application. It will work like a singleton.

One subclass of Application inherit the properties of Application and you can access to this class wherever you want using the command "Context.getApplicationContext()". Normally you will use this class to have everthing that need a global access. Example:

```
class YourName_App extends Application {

     private ArrayList<String> chatConversation;

     public String getChatConversation(){
        return this.chatConversation;
     }

     public void setChatConversation(ArrayList<String> chat){
        this.chatConversation = chat;
     }
}
```

And now your Chat Activity:

```
class Chat extends Activity {

     ArrayList<String> conversation;

     @Override
     public void onCreate(Bundle b)
     {
         ...
         YourName_App appState = ((YourName_App) getApplicationContext());
         conversation = appState.getChatConversation();
         ...
     }
}
```

It is done! This is the best way to do it.

Sorry for my poor english.

Comment: Don't forget to declare your application subclass in `AndroidManifest.xml`. ie. `<application android:name=".YourName_App" ... />`